# Scale an SVG element using a transform origin

Tags: html, css, svg, transform, scale

```html
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codepen.io/basement/pen/oepKxY.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://s.codepen.io/basement/debug/zdpVyV/PNAvYLZmJRQr"></iframe>
    
    <div class="wrp">  
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
           width="100" height="100"
           class="canvas"
      > 
        <defs>   
          <style type="text/css"> 
            polygon { fill: none; stroke-width: 0.5; stroke: #f00; }
          </style>       
        </defs>
        
        <g transform="translate( 0 12.5 ) scale( 1 )">
        
          <polygon 
            points="
              75,6.7
              75,93.3
              0,50
            " 
            transform="rotate( -30 50 50 )"
          />
          
        </g>   
        
      </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="origin.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make the red triangle in the snippet above scale larger while defining a specific transform origin. With the rotate attribute in SVG we can do this:

```
transform="rotate( -30 50 50 )"
```

The first value: `-30` rotates element counter-clockwise. The `50 50` defines the transform origin ( x and y respectively ). Can I do this with `scale`?. I want my red triangle to scale up but keep it's origin centered.

**Note:** *I know about `transform-origin` in CSS but I'm assuming the coordinate system that CSS uses will be relative to the whole web page or it's closest positioned element like it usually is... I want to define it in SVG coordinate terms like done with the rotate property.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate --> scale --> translate_back
e.g.

```
<g transform="translate( 0 12.5 ) translate( 50 50) scale( 1.5 ) translate( -50 -50)">
```

Explanation: Assuming you would like to use (50 50) as the scale origin, this will first translate your shape by (-50, -50) so that your desired scale origin will now be at (0, 0). Then you scale, and finally you reverse the translation to put the shape back where it were.

Comment: That is some weird behaviour. Why are the x and y coordinates scaled as well? In my opinion default behaviour of scale should only scale width and height and not incluse x and y.

Comment: Not at all. Actually this is the default behaviour for almost all graphics systems (2d and 3d) otherwise the overall scene composition will be destroyed after scaling. May be this example will help: assume you have two rectangles side by side in a scene (e.g. two neighbor houses in google map), and you scale the scene (zoom in/out the map), if only width and height were scaled and not x and y, the rectangles will overlap if scale > 1 or get detached if scale < 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
<style>
#<Some id> { 
    transform-box:fill-box; transform-origin: left;  transform:scale(0.3,1);
    fill:green;
}
</style>
```

This will scale with referencepoint on the left side of the bouding box of your SVG element.